# I want to Make my Gridview row vertical (like one row details after another)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview in asp.net which have some column.Now i want to show my result in Gridview in such a way that my first row header,below this row's each column details. After showing all the details in my row then i want to show another row below with columns of that row .
How can i do that ? 
I just add the picture which i think will help to understand.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqpbr.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share relevant code snippets.

Comment: I just tried so many times but don't understand how to solve this . I think it can be possible to make my Gridview  row vertical but again i think it can also be possible templatefield. But i can't do this as i have no idea about it .If you see my image i think you understand how i want my gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert one of the columns to **TemplateField**, then inside the *ItemTemplate* for this field add controls for the rest of the properties, for example:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerId">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="CustomerId">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Id</strong></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerName") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerName") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

[image]

In the previous code I used a table to wrap the controls just to show the idea, but you can use bootstrap, html, css , javascript code inside it.

Comment: Thanks.  It helps me a lot to get that concept .I was thinking that it would possible by making my gridview row vertical .Is there any blog or tutorial or any other way on this point so that i can enhance my design. Please help me out